# How to prove this inequality? $4(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2) \geq (a+b+c+d)^2$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

How do you prove:
$$4(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)\geq (a+b+c+d)^2.$$ Sorry for the inconvenience because I'm new and the picture's size is to big to be uploaded.

Comment: I mean, you tagged it. It's a special case of Cauchy-Schwarz that is the Quadratic Mean-Arithmetic Mean inequality.

Comment: Hint: CS & $1+1+1+1=4$.

Comment: The problem is C-S (Cauchy Schwarz Inequality) for $4$ variables. Other substitutions you can make yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a highschool trick, let me show you below:

Suppose a b c d are all real number,

[result (1)] $a^2+b^2-2ab=（a-b)^2>=0,then a^2+b^2>=2ab$

expand the right-handside and apply  [result (1)]

$（a + b + c + d）^ 2=（a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2 + d ^ 2）+2ab+2ac+2ad+2bc+2bd+2cd$

$（a + b + c + d）^ 2\leq（a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2 + d ^ 2）+(a^2+b^2)+(a^2+c^2)+(a^2+d^2)+(c^2+b^2)+(d^2+b^2)+(c^2+d^2)=4（a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2 + d ^ 2）$